# Why did Merle cut off his hand instead of cutting the handcuffs?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Something that has really bothered me in The Walking Dead was the part in the first season when Merle Dixon, after being handcuffed to some ducting on top of the building, uses a hacksaw to *cut off his hand.*

He had a hacksaw! Why didn't he cut through the handcuff chain? Or the metal rod the other cuff was attached to?

Has there ever been a reason given as to why he had to cut off his hand instead of the handcuff? Maybe in the comics or commentary or something?

Comment: Too dull to cut the metal? I can't find a quote, but people online say that is the reason.

Comment: or cut whatever he was attached to?

Comment: @JackBNimble - Confirmed by Daryl on the show when they discover the severed hand.

Comment: OP - Merle isn't in the comics, so they can't answer the question.

Comment: for future reference, if anyone needs to, cutting off your little finger all the way to the wrist, same/less pain, gets you out of the cuffs and you keep 80% of your hand.

Comment: He had everything he needed to pick the handcuff.  The worst case would be using the hacksaw to cut the soft angle iron holding the pipe and using that to pick the handcuff, but there are plenty of other things - perhaps some of the metal from his leather cuff, or maybe there were bits of wire, or simply using part of the hacksaw itself. He had full access to the keyway in the handcuff, and a little bit of effort would have released the locking pawl - it's not like a typical tumbler lock, all you have to do is force a little metal in there the right way and it would release.

Comment: @AdamDavis Ever been in handcuffs? It's not a matter of just jamming something in the lock. Very few people can escape handcuffs in real-life, the only way that some close to reliable is to snap the little bone at the base of your thumb.

Comment: @Kevin actually there's no evidence that anyone has ever escaped handcuffs breaking or dislocating their thumb. As long as both hands are cuffed behind the back, as long as the key entry is towards the arm and away from the hands, and as long as the person is under surveillance, then yes, picking a hand cuff is difficult even if you have pieces of metal. In this specific case, however, only one hand was cuffed, he wasn't under surveillance, and he could see and examine the cuffs and key entry. Cuffs are not meant to be unpickable - you can do it with a bobby pin - they are for compliance.

Comment: @BaneStar007 Good advice, but somehow I feel like that would be more painful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the script of season one, episode four, *Vatos*, in the scene where Daryl, T-Dog, and Rick find the severed hand:

> Daryl [to T-Dog]:  "You got a do-rag or something?"
>
> *T-Dog hands him one.*
>
> **Daryl: (sighs) "I guess the saw blade was too dull for the handcuffs."**
>
> *Daryl gingerly picks Merle’s hand up by a finger and examines the cut.*
>
> Daryl:  "Ain’t that a bitch."

The hacksaw blade was too dull to cut through metal, so Merle cut through flesh and bone, which are much softer. Better to cut off a hand than die of thirst, exposed on a scorching rooftop in Atlanta, during the summer.

In real life, handcuffs are (unsurprisingly) designed to be difficult to remove without the key, so it is entirely plausible that a dull hacksaw would be unable to cut off a pair of police cuffs.

It would be extremely difficult even for a person using both hands and a sharp hacksaw;  Merle is limited to using one hand to operate the saw.  If we assume he's a righty, he is even worse off, because it is his right hand that is chained to the roof - he can only use his weak hand to try to cut through hardened steel with a dull saw.

Comment: Also if memory serves the dead were making their way out onto the roof, greatly limiting his time.

Answer (score 5):

You've never used a hacksaw on hardened steel have you? I cut soft steel once as a tween, cutting a 2" steel pipe so I could make a periscope. It took me the better part of an hour. The steel on handcuffs is *much* stronger than that, and deliberately polished to make it even harder to get the blade set. He'd be long eaten by the time he got through it.

Comment: Except he wasn't under time pressure because of zombies, because they were barred from the building. Perhaps he was under time pressure because of starvation.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Summer in Georgia is hot.  Rooftops are even hotter.  He'd die of dehydration within a few days.

Comment: I have not had the need to cut hardened steel, but I have cut soft 1/2 inch bolts and 3/4 inch rebar. Both done with a really dull and cheap hacksaw blade, took me less than a minute both times. That was partly why I asked this question.

Comment: Bolts and rebar are both very soft compared to hardened steel. Rebar deliberately so, so they can bend it at the tips so it doesn't pull through the concrete (ever wonder why the top of a stack of installed rebars looks like a flower?). Just find any reasonable lock and try it yourself - not a $2 padlock, even a $10 combo lock will take you some time and that's not even close to what a good set of Smith & Wesson handcuffs uses.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Is that also true for the chain though? I can totally believe that of the handcuff metal, but what about the links in the chain? Seems like those would be doable, and what I was thinking of when I thought of cutting.

Comment: Oh yes, it is freakishly tough. It might have worked with a diamond or carborundum saw, but with a normal tool-steel blade the chain would be much harder and would simply burn off the teeth.

Comment: Something I'm still confused about: Ignoring the handcuffs, why couldn't he cut the screw that the cuffs were attached to? It looked low-quality, and no more than 1/2 and inch.

Comment: @isaacg: We can't know whether Merle tried that or not. It wasn't specifically addressed in the episode. It's just as possible (even more likely) that Merle exhausted every other option before trying to cut off his own hand.

Comment: Right before he cuts off his hand the zombies put pressure at the door and he does not know if it will hold long enough and panics under pressure and decides to take the fastest route to save his life